# linux cmd delete all files that without permissions

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, delete

In linux command prompt i have a folder that has about 10 files that different permissions how do i delete everyone that don't have permissions for the owner, to read ,write or execute in one command ?

Comment: Crossposted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284160/linux-cmd-how-to-delete-all-the-file-of-a-folder-that-dont-have-any-permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove all permissions from the files except owner permissions, you can simply us:

`chmod go-rwx <list_of_filenames>`

That will remove read, write, and execute permissions for group and others, regardless of whether the files already have those permissions or not.